# Keep active class in nav on page reload

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, reload

I have a list in navbar as follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav mx-auto">
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a href="home.html" class="nav-link">About us</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a href="mission.html" class="nav-link">Our mission</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a href="news.html" class="nav-link">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to keep the active class on page reload (after redirect to href in links), but it always flickers. 
So my question is how to keep active class on page reload?
I dont have `nav-tabs` and can't get jquery to keep class on page reload (it flickers until document is ready).

If I would have `nav-tabs` I could do something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (location.hash) {
        $("a[href='" + location.hash + "']").tab("show");
    }
    $(document.body).on("click", "a[data-toggle]", function(event) {
        location.hash = this.getAttribute("href");
    });
});
$(window).on("popstate", function() {
    var anchor = location.hash || $("a[data-toggle='tab']").first().attr("href");
    $("a[href='" + anchor + "']").tab("show");
});
```

But I have `nav-link` and not `nav-tabs`. `PHO` is not an option.

Best Regards

Comment: You have to look up how to use `localStorage` or `cookies` to achieve this

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I tried, but I could not make it work.

Comment: Then please show us what you have tried

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Updated.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen No ideas?